# In R, how could I plot three different value with 2 categoricl value using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a raw dataset.

```
  gender neg_sentiment neu_sentiment pos_sentiment
  <fct>          <int>         <int>         <int>
 1  F            24216         10070         14734
 2  M            372863        162281        239366
```

And I want to plot this dataset like the below picture.

[image]

Could you please help me make this??

And dput is like below:

```
structure(list(gender = structure(1:2, .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
neg_sentiment = c(24216L, 372863L), neu_sentiment = c(10070L, 
162281L), pos_sentiment = c(14734L, 239366L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape from wide to long and then (gg)plot using `facet_wrap`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(-gender) %>%
    ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = name)) +
    geom_col() +
    facet_wrap(~ gender)
```

[image]

---

Or after some more fine-tuning/polishing

```
df %>%
    pivot_longer(-gender) %>%
    mutate(name = factor(
        name,
        levels = c("pos_sentiment", "neu_sentiment", "neg_sentiment"),
        labels = c("positive", "neutral", "negative"))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = name)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
    facet_wrap(~ gender, strip.position = "bottom") +
    labs(x = "") +
    scale_fill_manual(
        values = c("positive" = "darkblue", "neutral" = "blue", "negative" = "darkred")) +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- structure(list(gender = structure(1:2, .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"),
neg_sentiment = c(24216L, 372863L), neu_sentiment = c(10070L,
162281L), pos_sentiment = c(14734L, 239366L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```